# Is there a way to fake file on file sistem or Write a file that visible only to my EXE file

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, adobe, activex

Ok i wrote and application that use Adobe ActiveX control for displaying PDF files.

Adobe ActiveX control load files only from file system. So i nead to feed a file path to this control.

Problem is that i don't want to store PDF files on file system. Event temporary! **I wan't to store my PDF files only in memory**, and i want to use Adobe ActiveX control.

**So i nead:**

1) A way to fake file on a file system. So this control would "think" that there is a file, but would load it from memory

2) A way to create file on file system that would be "visible" to only one application, so my PDF control could load it, and other users won't even see it..

3) Something else

**PS: I'm not asking to "finish my home work", i'm just asking - is there a way to do this?**

Comment: Well, no doubt you can create a virtual file system. For example Truecrypt does just that. But surely it would be easier to switch to a better PDF viewer?

Comment: Whatever the solution is to this, it will be 1000x harder than just using `%TEMP%`. Why not be practical?

Comment: Some controls allow you to "stream in" data. You'll need to check the documentation for the control to see if the Adobe control does that.

Comment: @tenfour I know, but i don't want user to copy my pdf files. And i don't want to convert them to something else (to doc, rtf, html). And ofcource Adobe PDF ActiveX control is really better at PDF rendering then any third party control (IMHO)

Comment: What's to stop them taking a screenshot? If something is on the user's PC, then there is nothing on earth you can do to stop them accessing it if they're determined enough. Even if you lock the file, power cycling the machine will mean it's left behind. Putting it in the temporary folder is enough of a deterrant to the vast majority of users...

Comment: I get it :) Tnx for so 'clear' explanation. I allready understand that, but i still want to make as much as i can to make users life more complicated. PS: about screenshot - i can block user keyboard :D

Comment: You are not serious about blocking the keyboard, right?

Comment: @tenfour I'm still thinking about it :D (it's actually intresting idia - but i don't think that USERS will LIKE that feature)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just a note - TrueCrypt does not create a virtual file system. They emulate a disk device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *almost* do it (means: no you can't, but you can do something that comes close).

Creating a file with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` *does* in principle create a file, temporarily. However, as long as there is sufficient buffer cache (which is normally always the case unless your file is tens to hundreds of megabytes), the system *will not write to disk*. This is not just something that happens accidentially, but the actual specified behaviour of this flag.

Further, specifying `0` as share mode and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` will prevent any other process from opening your file for as long as you keep it open, even if someone knows it's there, and the file will "disappear" when you close it. Even if your application crashes, the OS will clean up behind you (if DRM is the reason). If you're in super paranoia mode and worried about the system bluescreening while your file exists, you can additionally schedule a pending move too. This will, in case of a system crash, remove the file during boot.

Lastly, given NTFS, you can create an alternate stream with a random, preferrably unique name (e.g. SHA1 of the document or a UUID) on any file or even directory. Alternate streams on directories are ... a kind of nasty hack, but entirely legal and they work just fine, and don't appear in Explorer. This will not *really* make your file invisible, but nearly so (in almost every practical aspect, anyway). If you're a good citizen, you will want to use the system temp folder for such a thing, not the program folder or some other place that you shouldn't write to.
Creating an alternate stream is dead easy too, just use the normal file or directory name and append a colon (`:`) and the name of the stream you want. No extra API needed.

Other than that, it gets kind of hard. You can of course always create something like a ramdisk (would be tough to hide it, though), or try to use one of the stream-from-memory functions to fool an application into reading from a memory buffer on the allegation of a file... but that's not trivial stuff.

Comment: I know it's a stupid question. But can user somehow unlock file that under FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE while it's opened? With some tools like "Unlock IT" or something else?

Comment: Normally not, but in principle, someone who has physical access to a machine can do anything with it, at any time. The kernel won't normally let you do things like this, but you could just install a driver/rootkit that totally subverts all kernel security and lets you do anything with any file, even ones you don't own. Every antivirus software does that kind of thing. Or, one could use an active firewire port to overwrite kernel memory, even without administrator access...

Comment: Ok. tnx. I think.. Temp Folder + FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE + NTFS + SHEDULE.. will put me at ease :)

Comment: It really depends on how important/valuable your documents are. If you're trying to protect your country's nuclear weapon codes, you had better find another solution. On the other hand, if we're talking about a PDF that you can download from the internet for $20, this is perfectly sufficient. In that case it's much more hassle stealing it than just paying for it.

Comment: So i can't use it to protect nuclear weapon codes?.. shit! =_= my employers will be dissapointed :)

Answer (score 2):

If something needs to be on a file system to pass to another application, you can not hide it/limit it to certain processes. Anything your app can see, anything else at the same privilige level can also see/access. You may be able to lock it but how depends on why you want to protect against.

Remember that the user's PC is theirs, not yours so they have full access to everything on it.

Comment: Ok, but for example Windows Phone 7.x (mobile OS) have so called "Isolated Storage", so it prevents (to some extend) other applications and users to access files that saved in your application Isolated Storage. I know that on Windows there is Isolated Storage, but it isn't protected event from program called 'Explorer' :) so it's really easy to find a file that saved there..

Comment: This is not exactly so. You can limit access to the filesystem using filesystem filter driver.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp can you point me out on an article or some place in google where i can read about filesystem filter drivers? (is is hard to implement?)

Comment: @Ai_boy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968 . About 6 months of work to do it right.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp ow.. ok.. i get it :) i don't think it would be nessasary for me, at least for now. Anyway Tnx a lot for the link and for your advices

Answer (score 1):

You can create a virtual disk and limit access to it to only specific application. Do to this you would have to write a file system driver or a filesystem filter driver. Both work in kernel mode and are tricky to write and maintain. Our company offers components that let you avoid writing drivers yourself and write business logic in user-mode (we provide drivers in those products).

Your most obvious option is to get rid of Adobe Reader control and use some third-party component that displays PDFs and can load them from memory.

But in general a smart hacker would be able to capture your data unless you have (a) non-standard data format, and/or (b) stream the data from the server dynamically, not keeping the complete data on the computer. These are not bulletproof solutions either, but they make hacker's work much harder.